# How sort decimal numbers in MySQL saved as VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers

Unfortunately, I've run into a problem and I honestly don't know how to solve it.

I have numbers (unordered) stored as VARCHAR in my MySQL database:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15.1
15.2
15.3
15.4
15.5
15.6
15.7
15.8
15.9
15.10
15.11
15
16
17
18

Could anyone advise me how to sort them using SQL query in the following way?

This should be the result:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
15.1
15.2
15.3
15.4
15.5
15.6
15.7
15.8
15.9
15.10
15.11
16
17

Unfortunately, I've tried just about everything I can think of.

For example

```
SELECT meetings_points.number_of_points  
FROM meetings_points 
WHERE (`meetings_points`.`meeting` = 1026) 
ORDER BY 
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meetings_points.number_of_points, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meetings_points.number_of_points, '.', -1), '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meetings_points.number_of_points, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED),
  meetings_points.number_of_points ASC;
```

Unfortunately, it returns an incorrect result:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
**14
15.1
15.2
15.3
15.4
15.5
15.6
15.7
15.8
15.9
15.10
15.11
15**
16
17
18

Does anyone know how to sort these numbers?

Thank you very much

I tried this SQL (all wrong)

```
SELECT meetings_points.number_of_points  
FROM meetings_points 
WHERE (`meetings_points`.`meeting` = 1026) 
ORDER BY 
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meetings_points.number_of_points, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meetings_points.number_of_points, '.', -1), '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meetings_points.number_of_points, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED),
  meetings_points.number_of_points ASC;
```

```
SELECT meetings_points.number_of_points
FROM meetings_points
WHERE meetings_points.meeting = 1026
ORDER BY
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meetings_points.number_of_points, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meetings_points.number_of_points, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED),
  CAST(REPLACE(meetings_points.number_of_points, '.', '') AS UNSIGNED);
```

```
SELECT meetings_points.number_of_points
FROM meetings_points
WHERE (`meetings_points`.`meeting` = 1026)
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meetings_points.number_of_points, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
         CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meetings_points.number_of_points, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED),
         LENGTH(meetings_points.number_of_points),
         meetings_points.number_of_points
ASC;
```

```
SELECT number_of_points 
FROM meetings_points 
WHERE meeting = 1026 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_of_points, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED), SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_of_points, '.', -1) + 0;
```

```
SELECT number_of_points
FROM meetings_points
WHERE meeting = 1026
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_of_points, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
         CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(number_of_points, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED),
         IF(INSTR(number_of_points, '.') > 0, SUBSTRING(number_of_points, INSTR(number_of_points, '.')+1), '')
```

Comment: CAST to DECIMAL(5,2) then sort.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and format your code. As is the question looks like the data is stored in one varchar field separated by space.

Comment: Hi @Václav Kraus, we think we get answer for you now, please have a try. In short, extract the main point and suffix as seperate columns, cast them to integer and sort by them as integer instead of char. a special case to handle when there is no suffix at the point. (set suffix to 0 in that case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`like`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator within a [`case`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) statement to sort the data as you described.

1. Extract `main` as the string before the `'.'` char and convert it to
   unsigned int.
2. If the string has a `'.'` char, extract `suffix` as the
   string after the `'.'` char and convert it to unsigned int, otherwise
   set `suffix` as 0.
3. Sort the data by `(main, suffix)`

Here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e06675/1):

```
SELECT number_of_points,
       CAST(Substring_index(number_of_points, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED) AS main,
       (CASE
            WHEN number_of_points LIKE '%.%' THEN
                CAST(Substring_index(number_of_points, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED)
            ELSE
                0
        END
       ) AS suffix
FROM meetings_points
WHERE meeting = 1026
ORDER BY CAST(Substring_index(number_of_points, '.', 1) AS UNSIGNED),
         (CASE
              WHEN number_of_points LIKE '%.%' THEN
                  CAST(Substring_index(number_of_points, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED)
              ELSE
                  0
          END
         )
```

| number_of_points | main | suffix |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 8 | 0 |
| 9 | 9 | 0 |
| 10 | 10 | 0 |
| 11 | 11 | 0 |
| 12 | 12 | 0 |
| 13 | 13 | 0 |
| 14 | 14 | 0 |
| 15 | 15 | 0 |
| 15.1 | 15 | 1 |
| 15.2 | 15 | 2 |
| 15.3 | 15 | 3 |
| 15.4 | 15 | 4 |
| 15.5 | 15 | 5 |
| 15.6 | 15 | 6 |
| 15.7 | 15 | 7 |
| 15.8 | 15 | 8 |
| 15.9 | 15 | 9 |
| 15.10 | 15 | 10 |
| 15.11 | 15 | 11 |
| 16 | 16 | 0 |
| 17 | 17 | 0 |
| 18 | 18 | 0 |